# How to parallel bash for loop

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

How can I make this loop use the parallel linux command?

```
 func() {
     ssh -q $cn "systemctl restart ntpd"
 }

 
 for num in $(seq 30 40) ; do
    num_tmp=$(printf "%03d" $num)
    cn="node$num_tmp"    
    func
done | parallel
```

The func function changed according to the needs, basically it login to the node and run command(s) there

I tried to add parallel in the end of the loop as I saw but it dont work

Comment: You don't show your code for `func`, and the design is not optimal because it presumably uses a global variable. Can you recast your `func` to take a parameter so it is a better citizen and nicer to parallelise?

Answer (score 1):

Add this "&" to end the end of func;

```
 .....
    cn="node$num_tmp"    
    func &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe:

```
seq -f "%03G" 30 40 | parallel --dry-run 'ssh -q node{} "systemctl restart ntpd"'
```

**Sample Output**

```
ssh -q node030 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node031 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node032 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node033 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node034 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node035 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node036 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node037 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node038 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node039 "systemctl restart ntpd"
ssh -q node040 "systemctl restart ntpd"
```

Or, if you have bash v4 or newer, it can zero-pad for you:

```
parallel --dry-run 'ssh -q node{} "systemctl restart ntpd"' ::: {030..040}
```